# Relative row selection in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible in pandas to select the 5 rows *before/after* a specific row if they match a specific condition?

For instance, is it possible to start from row 19, and then select the five preceding rows for which b is True (thus selecting 16,16,10,7, and 4). I would call this 'relative' location. (Is there a better term for this? A place I can read about this type of lookup?)

```
a      |  b   
=============
0       True   
1       False
4       True
7       True
9       False
10      True
13      True
16      True
18      False
19      True
```

Comment: can you edit your df as it looks a bit weird, also is row 16 a column or an index value?

Comment: Are you trying to select the first 5 rows that match the condition?  Or in the first 5 rows, only the ones that match the condition?

Comment: @EdChum I reformatted it

Comment: @northsideknight good spot. I added more detail: I am looking to start from 19 and then select 16, 13, 10, 7, and 4.

Comment: In list comprehension you could do
[b for row in rows[:index] if row.b==True][:5]
I have no experience in pandas though, maybe this is a step in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
In [31]: df.ix[(df.b) & (df.index < df[df.a == 19].index[0])].tail(5)
Out[31]:
    a     b
2   4  True
3   7  True
5  10  True
6  13  True
7  16  True
```

Step by step:

index of the element where a==19:

```
In [32]: df[df.a == 19].index[0]
Out[32]: 9
```

now we can list all elements where `b is True` and which index is less than 9:

```
In [30]: df.ix[(df.b) & (df.index <9)].tail(5)
Out[30]:
    a     b
2   4  True
3   7  True
5  10  True
6  13  True
7  16  True
```

now combine both of them:

```
In [33]: df.ix[(df.b) & (df.index < df[df.a == 19].index[0])].tail(5)
Out[33]:
    a     b
2   4  True
3   7  True
5  10  True
6  13  True
7  16  True
```

Speed it up a little bit:

```
In [103]: idx19 = df[df.a == 19].index[0]

In [104]: idx19
Out[104]: 9

In [107]: %timeit df.ix[(df.b) & (df.index < df[df.a == 19].index[0])].tail(5)
1000 loops, best of 3: 973 µs per loop

In [108]: %timeit df.ix[(df.b) & (df.index < idx19)].tail(5)
1000 loops, best of 3: 564 µs per loop
```

PS so it got 42% faster

Comment: This largely does what expected, but it is really slow. Is there a way to speed this up?